# UNIX/Linux sparse files -- in use? How do you handle these?

Tags: backup, files, filesystems

Since the beginning the standard UNIX/Linux systems support sparse files, this is a file which contains unused space that is unallocated until needed.  To review, to generate via a C program: create a file, position to 2G, write ONE byte, close file.  Doing an ls -l shows the size to be 2G....however ls -ls shows the size in blocks to be closer to a one byte file.  If you logically access the file (i.e. cp sparse_file xxx) the resulting file xxx will indeed contain a fully allocated 2Gbytes.

I have created sparse files in the past as a testing vehicle for some of applications.  However, their existence has caused a few problems.

The important problem is that outside of the 'dump' program, backup programs and general procedures access these type of files logically and thus for a 1 byte sparse file one gets a backup w/ 2G of 0'd data.  This has caused some upset backup folks when I do this.

Any good solutions for this type of situation?

Comment: sorry I mispelled Linux in the title. :-(

Comment: Pro Tip: You don't need a custom program to create a sparse file, just dd: "dd if=/dev/zero of=sparse bs=1G seek=2 count=0".

Comment: or "truncate -s 1G sparse"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU Tar has the *--sparse* (*-S*) options that make working with spares files simple.

Answer (score 2):

Use a backup program that is capable of detecting and handling sparse files correctly.  There's plenty of them around (a la Jeremy's suggestion of tar with -S), just make it a checklist item on your backup system evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

rsync-based backup programs should be able to handle space files just fine (rsync has --sparce/-S options)

Answer (score 0):

The star program is much faster for sparse files than GNU tar.  It requires the -sparse option when handling such files.  For just plain copying use cp --sparse=auto