# Fast linux file creation

Tags: linux, filesystems

I want to create an empty (may not be zeroed) file in ext4 file system. I can do this with:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file count=xxxx
```

But it takes a while if x is around 0.5T. I suppose there is a way to to create such file fast. It may contain gibberish it does not matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a sparse file, but may not have the results you want depending on why you are doing this:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=sparse_file bs=1 count=1 seek=512M`

```
ls -l sparse_file        
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kbrandt kbrandt 536870913 2010-03-03 08:30 sparse_file
```

The problem is that if a program doesn't know how to handle sparse files, when do you something like copy the file, it will fill it with zeros.  For example, see [this previous serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/54040/unix-linux-sparse-files-in-use-how-do-you-handle-these).  You can see the difference with `du` as well:

```
[kbrandt@kbrandt-opadmin: /bigfiles] du sparse_file
12  sparse_file
[kbrandt@kbrandt-opadmin: /bigfiles] du sparse_file --apparent-size
524289  sparse_file
[kbrandt@kbrandt-opadmin: /bigfiles] #cat is not sparse aware, watch what happens
[kbrandt@kbrandt-opadmin: /bigfiles] cat sparse_file > sparse_file2 
[kbrandt@kbrandt-opadmin: /bigfiles] du sparse_file2
524808  sparse_file2
```

Lastly, if you do want to actually put in the zeros, if you set a higher bs it might be a little faster like bs=4096. [Here is a link](http://www.mail-archive.com/eug-lug@efn.org/msg12073.html) to someone who actually did some benchmarks with dd block sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Would a sparse file suffice?

```
% dd if=/dev/zero of=sparsefile bs=1k seek=500M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1024 bytes transferred in 0.000224 secs (4569114 bytes/sec)

% ls -lh sparsefile
-rw-------  1 james  james   500G  3 Mar 13:30 sparsefile
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
truncate -s 500G filename
```

It is **really** fast if your filesystem supports sparse files.

File contents are zeroed, always. Linux won't allow you to reuse disk sectors without zeroing them since this is a security risk. For sparse files, sectors are only allocated when they are first written to.